# Can I use synthetic division??

Tags: polynomials

Find the quotient and remainder when $2x^4+7x^3+x^2+x+4$ is divided by $2x+1$

Here coefficient of $x$ is $2$ in divisor.

Can we use here division algorithm?? 
Taking $x=-1/2$ and using synthetic division I got

Remainder is $3$

And quotient $2x^3+6x^2-2x+2$
Which I can simply to $x^3+3x^2-x+1$ (since $-1/2$ is a divisor of 2$)
Which is the answer

Guys what is your opinion??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use synthetics division with $$x=-1/2$$ you get $$ P(x) = (x+1/2)Q(x) +R$$

Thus to get your original division you need to modify your Q(x).

$$ P(x) = (x+1/2)Q(x) +R \iff P(x) = (2x+1)Q^* (x) +R$$

Where $$Q^* (x) = (1/2) Q(x)$$

In our problem $$Q(x) = 2x^3+6x^2-2x+2$$ and $R=3$

Thus we get $$ Q^*(x) = x^3+3x^2-x+1$$ with $R=3$

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$(2x+1)(x^3+3x^2-x+1)=2x^4+7x^3+x^2+x+1$$ so the remainder is equal to $$3$$

Comment: Then my process will be right?

Comment: Yes, the remainder is #3#, but i can not see what you've written on you sheet.

Comment: OK I forgot to add an image but thanks for the help

Comment: But you know now, that your result $3$ is right.